Why is the adm group named adm? What does adm stand for?
According to the Debian wiki:

adm: Group adm is used for system monitoring tasks. Members of this group can read many log files in /var/log, and can use xconsole. Historically, /var/log was /usr/adm (and later /var/adm), thus the name of the group.

This explains that the group adm is named after the legacy command adm. But what is that command named after? What do the letters A.D.M stand for? Is "adm" short for something?

It’s short for administration or administrator.
Incidentally, /usr/adm was a directory, not a command.
